# Pass parameters to SQL Reporting Services report from WebBrowser control.

Tags: vb.net

How can one pass parameters to a report hosted on sql server reporting services and viewed in a webbrowser control in a .net desktop application.  I can easily open a report that does not contain parameters but i need to be able to provide parameters in a specific scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the parameter values via query strings in the URL.  See [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/pass-a-report-parameter-within-a-url) on the specific rules but here is an example:

```
YourWebBrowserControl.Navigate("http://YourDomain.Com/ReportServer/Name?parameter1=value&parameter2=1")
```